# Dynamic System in a circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following system of differential equations

$$
\dot{x} = -1-y+x^2\\ \dot{y}= x + xy
$$

So, it's easy to sketch the vector field but I have to prove that every solution that starts in the unit circle ($x^2+y^2 =1 $) should keep in the circle.

I can see it from the vector field but I don't know how to prove formally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the dot product of position vector with speed vector

$$x(\dot x)+y(\dot y)=x(-1-y+x^2)+y(x+xy)=x^3-x+xy^2=x(x^2+y^2-1)$$

is zero if we assume that $x^2+y^2=1.$

Indeed $2\vec{OM} . (\vec{OM})'$ is the derivative of $\vec{OM}.\vec{OM} = \|\vec{OM}\|^2.$

Having this derivative equal to zero means that $\|OM\|^2=const.$, therefore $\|OM\|$=const...

It is indeed very apparent in the figure I have obtained with a Matlab program with different initial conditions (materialized by little stars) :

[image]

Comment: Ok, I can see it, but it doesn't clear to me why the solutions have to be in the circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that since
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
$$rr'=xx'+yy'$$
$$=-x-xy+x^3+xy+x^2y^2$$
$$=-x(1-y^2)+xx^2$$
$$=x(x^2+y^2-1)$$
$$=x(r^2-1)$$
is equal to 0 when $r=1$.  Since $r'=0$ when $r=1$, solutions on the unit circle stay on the unit circle.

Comment: It gets to the same place, but the starting point to show $r'=0$ is more intuitive.